# Can i define constructor and private variables in Observer?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have two methods in my observer defined in `config.xml`.

If i want to add other methods in the observer.php that they will not catch any event:

Should i define them to `config.xml`?
And If i put some variables like `private $myvar` will I be able to use them?

Can I use a constructor?

Answer (score 3):

An observer in Magento is a class like any other. You can add constructors, private variables or any other class element that takes your fancy and you do not have to add these to the config.xml.

For example, you could make an observer class like this:

```
<?php
class Companyname_Modulename_Model_Observer {

  private $monkey = 'hi, I am a monkey';

  public function __construct() {
    $this->monkey = 'hi, I am still a monkey';
  }

  public function myObserverFunction($observer) {
    var_dump($this->showMonkeyString());
  }

  private function showMonkeyString() {
    return $this->monkey;
  }
}
```

In config.xml, you only add the function that you want to execute when your event occurs, something like:

```
  <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_category_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <does_not_matter_what_we_call_this_tag>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Companyname_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>myObserverFunction</method>
                    </does_not_matter_what_we_call_this_tag>
                </observers>
            </catalog_category_load_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

The output when you load a random category in your store will be 'hi, I am still a monkey'.

Answer (score 1):

An observer is a PHP class.

Only constraint is that function(Method) name you have entered while associating it with an event should be there.

Apart from that you can do whatever PHP allows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor in Observer

See following Observer classes in Magento1

```
class Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected $_parentProductIds = array();
    protected $_productIdsMassupdate = array();

    protected function _construct() {}
```

and

```
class Mage_Rss_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Factory instance
     *
     * @var Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
     */
    protected $_factory;

    /**
     * Application instance
     *
     * @var Mage_Core_Model_App
     */
    protected $_app;

    /**
     * @param array $args
     */
    public function __construct(array $args = array())
    {
        $this->_factory = !empty($args['factory']) ? $args['factory'] : Mage::getSingleton('core/factory');
        $this->_app = !empty($args['app']) ? $args['app'] : Mage::app();
    }
```